# Ошибка при сохранении данных. Wpf,Wcf,MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wcf

Всем добрый день, возникает подобная ошибка при сохранении данных в бд. Использую для связи с бд службу wcf, на ней описаны методы для сохранения, в клиенте подключение и сохранение данных осуществляется через MVVM.Ошибка возникает только в таблицах, где существуют связи. Редактирование существующих записей проходит на ура, также проверил через WCfTest и все запросы проходят на ура.Кину код на сохранение в клиенте и в службе, если нужно что-то больше, скажите скину. Прошу очень помочь, не знаю в какую сторону гуглить.Всем заранее спасибо!!

Метод на сохранение в классе.

```
public void SaveStudent(student st)
    {
        using (var context = new Service1Client())
        {
            if (st != null)
            {
               //ошибка возникает здесь
                context.AddNewStudent(st);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Не все данные заполнены!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Метод на сохранение в службе

```
public void AddNewStudent(student stud)
    {
        using (var context = new electron_journalEntities1())
        {
            var result = context.students.Find(stud.id_stud);
            if (result != null)
            {
                context.Entry(result).CurrentValues.SetValues(stud);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            else
            {
                context.students.Add(stud);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

И метод на сохранение в на самой форме WPF

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        stm.SaveStudent(((StudentVM)sTUDENTDataGrid.SelectedItem).STUDENT);
        stm.GetStudentModel();
    }
```

[image: Сама ошибка]

Comment: Хотелось бы увидеть InnerException. Слету могу предположить, что у  Вас есть поле по которому Ваш студент связан с сущностью specialty_group  и  в новом студенте  это поле не заполнено.

Comment: проблема таилась в самом классе, было лишнее поле, которое при передаче через метод было пустым, а к заполнению было обязательно. благополучно уже проект был закончен